# Is there a way to be notified when an app is published in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Is there any trick/functionality to get informed, when an app is published.

Reason: Publishing an app in  Google Play takes different durations. In my experience it is between half a day and 2 hours. To be the first to do the final test it would be interesting to know when the app is published.

Of course, there is alpha and beta testing abilities, but either I like to be the first that downloads the productive version :-)

Comment: You can put a 'production' version into the alpha section and make it so you're the only one able to install it. Once your happy with it you simply select to 'publish' it. You basically answered your own question.

Comment: No I didn't :-) Because this way i will not be notified. Doing this all by hand is clear, but can we be informed/fetched/notified in any way ?

Comment: OK, I worded that badly. If you want to be the first to download then just do what I said with an alpha release. There is no way to be notified when an app goes 'live'. Besides - if it's in 'production' what makes you think you'll download it before someone else?

Comment: So the answer is no. it is not possible. With the alpha I know howto do, because I already mentoined it in my question. If it is in production I would like to test it as soon as possible. Who know what all can happen, even it is the same version already tested in Beta. Of course someone else could be faster. I uploaded a new app this morning and it is still not active after 4 hours.

Comment: **"I already mentoined it in my question."** :yes, that's what I meant when I originally said you had answered your own question but I worded it badly. My point is simply this...if you want to be the first to download a production / release version of your app then the only way to do it is restrict access. There is nothing to stop you uploading it to the alpha section even if it is a release version. Just make sure you're the only one who can access the alpha section. When you're happy with the first download then put it into a release / production state.

Comment: I guess I have to follow that way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I just found this in the developer preferences in case it's helpful still: [image]

Comment: This answer is miss leading: those email does not exist for app publishing approval, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77044498/2127277

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Developer Console now notifies you when your app is live in the store through the notification icon:

[image]