# Is there a way to be notified when a release is approved in the Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I did not find a way to be notified when a release in the Google Play console is approved by Google team (and then I manually publish it the store) like "google has reviewed the app and it is now ready to publish".

It's annoying to visit the console every hour to know if the review process of my update is approved.

I already searched a solution with CI/CD like Bitrise or even tried to scrape the Google Play Console but no success.

Comment: The manual release process seems like an after thought and most of the Play console integrates it terribly.

Comment: Totally agree with that. When you publish (both with manual release process) two updates on two different channels (Release and Beta for example), if those two releases are approved, you CAN'T publish them one by one. You are forced to publish them together in store. Not very flexible..

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, @CyrilNiobé?

Comment: @Tokke the Google Dev Console app mobile is now pushing notifications when the review is done :)

Comment: @CyrilNiobé, does that mean Android only?  I can't find it on the iOS AppStore

Comment: @Tokke yes the app is only available on Google Play Store

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: as of October 2021, the "Play console" app is now sending notification when your pending release is approved by Google and ready to be published in the store (even when manual publishing is enabled)

Comment: Hi, is it activated by default or have I to activate it somewhere?

Comment: I do not remember activating it but suddenly receive notifications so I guess it's just by default.

Comment: Notification is hard to catch programmatically, email or api would be a better fit

Comment: This answer is miss leading: those email does not exist for app publishing approval, see my answer.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa With the configuration settings above, I **always** receive an email when an app is published or rejected. Not sure why this isn't working for you.

Comment: Can you show the mail subject and body of both somehow ? Because I don't get those emails and my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77044498/2127277 from google support state this cannot be true.

Answer (score 6):

## Notification management

1. Go to Play Console
   https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers
2. Choose your developer account
3. From the left menu choose:
   `Setup` > `Notifications`
4. In section `App updates` check `Email`

[image]

Comment: This is not relevant to the question

Comment: I believe this is relevant to the question. I was also looking for a way to get notified when the app moves from reviewed to live.

Comment: This answer is miss leading: those email does not exist for app publishing approval, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As of June 2023, the screenshot from another answer is no longer current.

Here's the updated screenshot:

[image: Google Play Notification Settings]

Comment: This answer is miss leading: those email does not exist for app publishing approval, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to activate and receive the email notification when publishing state of the app change, but we were never received them and contacted google play support. This is there answer :

[image: be notified when play store approve app publishing]

Their answer is pretty clear : This is not possible, you can only get notified when the app publishing is rejected.

Comment: Please do not include text as screenshots. *Cite* instead.

Answer (score -3):

Yup. If you grab the Google Play Console app you can configure notifications in-app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole

Comment: Are you sure there is a notification for "google has reviewed the app and it is now ready to publish"? When using managed publishing?

Comment: @O'Rooney no there is not unfortunately. This was exactly my question.

Comment: I downvoted this because it literally doesn't answer the question. Sorry @ljdawson.

Comment: Then I changed my mind and decided although it doesn't answer the question, it does provide some peripheral information that could be useful.

Comment: This answer is miss leading: those email does not exist for app publishing approval, see my answer.